# How to use the full variable value by mentioning some part of it in command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, variable

I want to create a script where I can just use a variable by mentioning some part of its string in arguments
for example :

```
#!/bin/bash

ipv4_5784_4679=1.1.1.1
ipv4_7838_7782_8987=2.2.2.2

echo "Ip of the port is = value"
```

I want to do it like running the script
`./script.sh 5784`
the output should be as

```
Ip of the port is = 1.1.1.1
```

`./script.sh 7782`
the output should be as

```
Ip of the port is = 2.2.2.2
```

But if the string comes as `84_46, _7838, 838_` it should throw an error.

Actually I am trying to create a script where I do not want to remember the IPs of that vm, all my apps are running on different VM with different ports

I tried to search on google, but unfortunately I am new to scripting I was not sure exactly what to search so could not get any specific results

Comment: check out `fzf` (fuzzy finder) -- it is not _exactly_ what you are asking for, but it could work for your use case.

Comment: perhaps something like `value=$(set | grep -E "^ipv4.*_$1[_=]" | sed -E 's/.*=.(.*)./\1/' | tr -d '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

The key concept here is to store your data in a form that is conducive to the operations you want to perform on it.

My suggestion would be an associative array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A ips=(
  [ipv4_5784_4679]=1.1.1.1
  [ipv4_5784_4680]=1.1.1.2
  [ipv4_7838_7782_8987]=2.2.2.2
)

readarray -t idx < <(printf '%s\n' "${!ips[@]}" | grep -E "_$1($|_)")

printf '%d match(es) found\n' ${#idx[@]}
for i in "${idx[@]}"
do
        printf 'IP of %s is %s\n' "$i" "${ips[$i]}"
done
```

This code stores the host-to-IP lookup table in an array `ips` where the router string is the index of the array element, and the IP number is the value of the array element.  For a parameter `$1` given on the command line, the script passes the list of indices `"${!ips[@]}"` through the `grep` utility to create an array `${idx[@]}` which contains all indices which match `$1`.  The output from the script is the number of indices found `${#idx[@]}` and the value pair of each index and its corresponding value.

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh 7838
1 match(es) found
IP of ipv4_7838_7782_8987 is 2.2.2.2
$ ./test.sh 7782
1 match(es) found
IP of ipv4_7838_7782_8987 is 2.2.2.2
$ ./test.sh 4679
1 match(es) found
IP of ipv4_5784_4679 is 1.1.1.1
$ ./test.sh 5784
2 match(es) found
IP of ipv4_5784_4680 is 1.1.1.2
IP of ipv4_5784_4679 is 1.1.1.1
$ ./test.sh 5784_4680
1 match(es) found
IP of ipv4_5784_4680 is 1.1.1.2
$ ./test.sh 84
0 match(es) found
$ ./test.sh 987
0 match(es) found
$ ./test.sh ipv4
0 match(es) found
$ ./test.sh ipv4_7838
0 match(es) found
```